# Dynamically generate textbox to match sum

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to generate Dynamic Text Box
Starting with two textboxes.

> > **if the value is less than the value in the first textbox then generate another textbox dynamically and let the user enter more values.
> >
> >     This has to be done till the sum of the values of all the text boxes from the second to the last one generated becomes equal to the value of first textbox.**

Of course other things need to be generated with the textboxes as well like lables etc. and positioned correctly so i thought of using a grid and generate the grid dynamically but above that i'm lost.

Any Help?

Thanks

---

i used a scrollviewer with the following code

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="8,8,8,14.417" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <Grid Margin="8" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" x:Name="amtGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="103"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="324"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="218"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ComboBox x:Name="crdrnextrows" Margin="32.367,8,8,7.423" SelectedIndex="1" />
        <ComboBox Background="#FFC6C3C6" Margin="8" x:Name="comboboxCr" GotKeyboardFocus="comboboxCr_GotKeyboardFocus" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBox Background="#FFC6C3C6" Foreground="White" IsEnabled="True" Margin="7.973,8,8,8" x:Name="txtBoxam1" Grid.Column="2" LostFocus="txtBoxam1_LostFocus"/>
        <TextBox Background="#FFC6C3C6" Foreground="White" IsEnabled="True" Margin="8,8,33.972,8" x:Name="txtBoxamt2" Grid.Column="3" LostFocus="textBox4_LostFocus"/>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

There is another textbox above that with similar code but without the scroll viewer, now what i was thinking was to dynamically create instances of the grid shown in the scrollviewer as many times as need to make them equal.

Is it possible to create new instances of the same grid and add them to the scollviewer dynamically with code?

Thanks

Comment: Dude you need to more specific then "the value less then the value in the first".

Comment: I mean that eg. if i enter 10000 in the first textbox and in the second textbox i enter 5000 then another textbox should be generated to enter the remaining 5000 and if the entered amount in the new textbox added to the previous values still doesn't add up to 10000 then another textbox should be generated. This goes on till the added values of all the textboxes become equal to 10000. Hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the additional information that you gave and given the complexity of the object you are wanting to create, a [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol.aspx) would probably be the best fit. This code is an example using a `DoubleClick` to show how to add the UserControl to your ScrollViewer.  You will need to expose properties in the `UserControl` in order to get the information from your TextBoxes otherwise the Code should be simular to my earlier answer.

i.e:

**UserControl Xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="70" d:DesignWidth="985">
    <Grid Margin="8" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" x:Name="amtGrid" Height="40">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="103"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="324"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="218"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ComboBox x:Name="crdrnextrows" Margin="32.367,8,8,7.423" SelectedIndex="1" />
        <ComboBox Background="#FFC6C3C6" Margin="8" x:Name="comboboxCr" GotKeyboardFocus="comboboxCr_GotKeyboardFocus" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBox Background="#FFC6C3C6" Foreground="White" IsEnabled="True" Margin="7.973,8,8,8" x:Name="txtBoxam1" Grid.Column="2" LostFocus="txtBoxam1_LostFocus"/>
        <TextBox Background="#FFC6C3C6" Foreground="White" IsEnabled="True" Margin="8,8,33.972,8" x:Name="txtBoxamt2" Grid.Column="3" LostFocus="txtBoxamt2_LostFocus"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Window Xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="123" Width="1098" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" MouseDoubleClick="Window_MouseDoubleClick">

    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel Name="stackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
            <my:UserControl1 x:Name="userControl11" Width="1077" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>

</Window>
```

**Main Window Code**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1 newUserControl = new UserControl1();
        newUserControl.Width = userControl11.Width;
        newUserControl.Height = userControl11.Height;
        stackPanel1.Children.Add(newUserControl);
    }

}
```

---

Here is a basic idea, I am using a `StackPanel` to hold the `TextBox's` you may want to use a `DockPanel` to hold your labels and etc and add that to the `StackPanel`.

**Xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Name="myContainer">
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" KeyDown="textBox1_KeyDown" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" KeyDown="textBox2_KeyDown"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Collection<Control> myControls = new Collection<Control>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myControls.Add(textBox2);
    }


    private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            int temp;
            int sum;
            sum = 0;
            foreach (TextBox tb in myControls)
            {
                if (int.TryParse(tb.Text, out temp))
                {
                    sum += temp;
                }
            }
            int test = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out test))
            {
                if (sum < test)
                {
                    TextBox newtb = new TextBox();
                    newtb.Width = ((TextBox)sender).Width;
                    newtb.Height = ((TextBox)sender).Height;
                    newtb.Margin = new Thickness(((TextBox)sender).Margin.Left, ((TextBox)sender).Margin.Top , ((TextBox)sender).Margin.Right , ((TextBox)sender).Margin.Bottom);
                    newtb.HorizontalAlignment = ((TextBox)sender).HorizontalAlignment;
                    newtb.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(textBox2_KeyDown);
                    myContainer.Children.Add(newtb);
                    myControls.Add(newtb);
                    newtb.Focus();
                }
                else
                    this.Background = Brushes.LightBlue;
            }
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            textBox2.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the collection to the item.  Then in the set add to the collection as necessary.

```
 public class dynamicInts
 {
     private int dInt;
     private ObservableCollection<DynamicInt> dynamicInts

     public int DInt 
     {
         get { return dInt; }
         set 
         {
             value = dInt;
             int sumInt;
             foreach (DynamicInt di in dynamicInts) sumInt += di.Dint)
             if (sumInt < 2*dynamicInts) dynamicInts.add(newdynamicInts ...
```